# Can Heroku save files to Github?

Tags: csv, github, heroku, push, pull

I have a code that actively updates .csv files that's currently hosted on heroku and everything is saved on github. Can heroku update the github with the new .csv files?

Comment: It is bad practice to version/commit data. If possible you should revise your idea.

Comment: Right now I just have it on a google cloud compute instance, where it saves the files there and I can get them if I need to. Any suggestions on a way to save data between restarts and host it

Comment: Use a database. That's how you achieve data persistence on Heroku as well. For example postgresql, mongodb, etc.